# Subscribe event not getting called everytime

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I am having search screen and when the user is navigated to results page,there are radio buttons with values (Minutes,Characters) on results page.

I have subscribed to the radio button click event on the results page,when ever the user clicks the radio button subscribe function should call.

Now the issue is:

1)When the user first time hits the search button,results are displayed.

2)User selects "Minutes" radio button the subscribe event is called and working.

3)User selects back button and user is redirected to search screen.

4)User hits the search button,results are dsiplayed.

5)User tries to click the ""Characters" button,the subscribe event is not called.

Hers is my code:

```
<div class="nmc-righttab" style="width: 60%">
    <div class="nmc-righttab" style="margin-left:20px">
        <label class="nmc-label" style="line-height:21px">@Res.Trends.DisplayResultBy</label>
    </div>
    <div class="nmc-righttab" style="width:250px">
        <div class="nmc-lefttab" style="margin-left:5px">
            <input type="radio" id="MinuRadio" name="GphInterval" value="2" data-bind="checked:GraphClick" />
        </div>
        <div class="nmc-righttab">
            <label class="nmc-label" for="MinuRadio" style="line-height:21px">@Res.Trends.Minutes</label>
        </div>
        <div class="nmc-lefttab" style="margin-left:5px">
            <input type="radio" id="CharRadio" name="GphInterval" value="3" data-bind="checked:GraphClick" />
        </div>
        <div class="nmc-righttab">
            <label class="nmc-label" for="CharRadio" style="line-height:21px">@Res.Trends.Characters</label>
        </div>
    </div></div>
```

JS Code:

```
  this.GraphClick.subscribe(function (val) {
      model.showGraphResults(true);
      model.GraphIntervalSelected(val);
      searchSpeechGraphView(speechUsage);
  }, this)
```

Comment: any errors in console you got ? can you check

Comment: I dont see any errors.its plain.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing `this` as a parameter to the `subscribe` method, why dont you bind that anonymous function with `this` object. like this

**JS Code:**

```
this.GraphClick.subscribe(function (val) {
  model.showGraphResults(true);
  model.GraphIntervalSelected(val);
  searchSpeechGraphView(speechUsage);
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: Nothing in the function references `this`, though.

Comment: @RoyJ : yes, but usually its good practice to bind the function to the target `this` object than to `this` object in scope.

Comment: @AJAYcHIGURUPATI : could you replicate your issue in jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net